# Why does a plane's vertexdata contain 52 entries?

Tags: away3d, vertices, vertex-array, uv-mapping

I'm new in 3D land and have experimented with several engines to get started. I have settled on away3D for it's simplicty.

I am creating creating a plane and sticking a texture on it, and want to be able to animate the texture by changing the UV data in realtime.

```
var plane:Mesh = new Mesh(new PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 1, 1), textMat);
```

These lines both return 52:

```
CompactSubGeometry(plane.geometry.subGeometries[0]).UVData.length;
plane.subMeshes[0].vertexData.length;
```

As far as I understood in other engines, vertexdata contains 3 values for each vertex (x, y, z). Considering a that a plane can be build out of either 4 or 6 vertices that would result in either 12 or 18 vertices values for the entire vertexarray.

UVData array would usually contain a U and V value for each corresponding vertex, which would result in less values than the vertexarray. But the UVdata and vertexData array have the same length here.

I tried asking on the away3D forum, but got no response, and my knowledge of 3D is still to small to understand any of the away3d sourcecode.

Could anyone explain why the vertexData and UvData contain so many values, and what they represent?

Answer (score 1):

http://away3d.com/forum/viewthread/4854/

vertexData = num_vertices * (x,y,z,Nx,Ny,Nz,Tx,Ty,Tz,u,v,Su,Sv)

laneGeometry(10, 10, 1, 1)

52 = 4 * 13

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, could you and add more detail to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a mesh, using new PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 1, 1) you should get 12 items in vertexData and 8 items in UVData. They correspond to:

vertexData: 4 vertices * 3 (x,y,z values).
UVData: 4 vertices * 2 (u,v values).